# document.form.submit() not working within jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit

I have a form that when I submit it will check for some validation through jQuery AJAX call.

My code is like this:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?php echo base_url();?>bTransJual/formTambahJual/ajaxCekStockJual/",
        data:  { prdIdUkuId: dataArrPrIdUkuId, qty: dataArrQty},
        dataType : "json",            
        success: function(data){
           if(data.sukses){
              //validasi lolos
              document.frmTransJual.submit();                                             
           }else{
              //validasi gagal
              psnErrNya = data.psnErr;
              $("#psnNotifikasiAjax").html(psnErrNya);
              $("#notifikasiAjax").show('normal');
              $("#imgLoadSubmit").hide();                                       
              return false;
           }
        }
     });
});
```

And my form tag:

```
<form name="frmTransJual" id="myForm" method="post" action="some_url.php">
```

If the ajax success it will return a value data, and if this data.sukses is true I want the form to submit it. i use document.frmTransJual.submit(); to submit it, but it doesn't work. anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: Note: Your `return false;` does nothing, as you cannot return from an AJAX callback.

Comment: Is that the only form on your page?

Comment: yes, that is the only form from mypage

Comment: Side note: Damn you need to work on creating easier to read for IDs and variables, I would kill someone if I had to read that code after someone. haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are using a infinite loop.It will call the same funciton again.

you can use like this

create a div

```
 `<div id="submit">Submit form</div>`


 $("#submit").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>bTransJual/formTambahJual/ajaxCekStockJual/",
    data:  { prdIdUkuId: dataArrPrIdUkuId, qty: dataArrQty},
    dataType : "json",            
    success: function(data){
       if(data.sukses){
         $("myform").submit();                                             
       }else{
          //validasi gagal
          psnErrNya = data.psnErr;
          $("#psnNotifikasiAjax").html(psnErrNya);
          $("#notifikasiAjax").show('normal');
          $("#imgLoadSubmit").hide();                                       
          return false;
       }
    }
 });
```

})

Comment: ho.. okey.. i get it now..
so it's just imposibble to do it then. :)

Comment: You can do this by creating a simple div and add a ajax call to that div.if it returns true than submit this form so that your server will get the value

Comment: what do you mean by "add a ajax call to that div"
can you give me a demo code for that? thanks before

Comment: well i get it now, that's should do it then.
Thank you very much @jhonraymos

Answer (score 1):

`document.frmTransJual` is the same form as `$("#myForm")`.  So, calling `document.frmTransJual.submit();` will just call the `submit` function again, in an infinite loop.

Comment: so is there any way i can make this form to submit when the ajax call success? or there is absolutely no way to do that because it's imposibble?

Comment: Why do you want to do an AJAX call before submitting the form?  Usually you POST a form normally, or you use AJAX to post it, why do you want to do both?  If you want to redirect, just use `window.location`.

Comment: actually the form has many value in it..i think i will be better if the input for the form get validated first before the form make a POST.

if i validate through php, then i have to fill the input again with the user input which is a lot...

thanks for your information btw for this, very appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The "A" in "AJAX" is for "asynchronous". Your `submit` handler function returns long before your AJAX call is complete, returning `false` from the `else` branch of your AJAX callback cannot affect the return value your `submit` callback.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the submit will not wait for the AJAX request to be completed.. It is asynchronous..

By the time the call comes out of callback function the request is long gone.

Comment: so is that means that's just imposibble to do it? submit this form when the ajax call is completed?